# NUnit.Framework: How to run categories with AND and OR option?

Tags: nunit

**NUnit.Framework: How to run categories with AND and OR option?**

I have defined my categories in test methods like:

1st Method:

```
[<Test>]
   [<Category("Smoke")>]
   [<Category("Reg")>]
```

2nd Method:

```
[<Test>]
   [<Category("Sanity")>]
   [<Category("Reg")>]
```

3rd Method:

```
[<Test>]
   [<Category("Sanity")>]
   [<Category("Smoke")>]
```

4th Method:

```
[<Test>]
   [<Category("Reg")>]
   [<Category("Login")>]
```

I am able to filter and run a specific test by using: dotnet test --filter TestCategory=Smoke

Now my requirement is to run:
1) All methods that have the category of Sanity AND Smoke (which in the above case should run only 3rd method). I tried: **dotnet test --filter "TestCategory=Sanity" && "TestCategory=Smoke"** but it's not working.

2) All methods that have either the category of Sanity or Smoke (which in the above case should run all except 4th). I tried: **dotnet test --filter "TestCategory=Sanity" || "TestCategory=Smoke"** but it's not working.

Please suggest how I can run AND and OR when it comes to run NUnit category wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dotnet test --filter <expression>` option takes a single argument, which is a filter expression. You are providing three arguments.

Additionally, since you are using the `dotnet test` command, you have to use operators and traits recognized by Microsoft. Operators from NUnit's Test Selection Language won't work unless they are also used by Microsoft.

In this case, you are looking for `dotnet test --filter "TestCategory=Sanity|TestCategory=Smoke"`

Note that you need to escape characters in the above expression as required by the command shell you are using. On Windows, I believe the double quotes will work. On Linux, depending on your shell, you might need to use single quotes.

The syntax for filter expressions is pretty well covered here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test

Comment: Thanks @charlie these worked dotnet test --filter "TestCategory= Sanity|TestCategory=Smoke"
dotnet test --filter "TestCategory= Sanity&TestCategory=Smoke"